# Rebuild Docker container on file changes

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

For running an ASP.NET Core application, I generated a dockerfile which build the application and copys the source code in the container, which is fetched by Git using Jenkins. So in my workspace, I do the following in the dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY src src
```

While Jenkins updates the files on my host correctly with Git, Docker doesn't apply this to my image.

My basic script for building:

```
#!/bin/bash
imageName=xx:my-image
containerName=my-container

docker build -t $imageName -f Dockerfile  .

containerRunning=$(docker inspect --format="{{ .State.Running }}" $containerName 2> /dev/null)

if [ "$containerRunning" == "true" ]; then
        docker stop $containerName
        docker start $containerName
else
        docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name $containerName $imageName
fi
```

I tried different things like `--rm` and `--no-cache` parameter for `docker run` and also stopping/removing the container *before* the new one is build. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It seems that docker is updating the image correctly, as the call of `COPY src src` would result in a layer id and no cache call:

```
Step 6 : COPY src src
 ---> 382ef210d8fd
```

What is the recommended way to update a container?

My typical scenario would be: The application is running on the server in a Docker container. Now parts of the app are updated, e.g. by modifying a file. Now the container should run the new version. Docker seems to recommend building a new image instead of modifying a existing container, so I think the general way of rebuilding like I do is right, but some detail in the implementation has to be improved.

Comment: Can you list the exact steps you've taken to build your container, including your build command and entire output from each command?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

### Video with visual explanation (from 2022)

[image: Visual video explanation container vs images]

Since I got a lot of positive feedback [to my previous, first visual explanation](https://youtu.be/ktrxCC77uTQ), I decided to create another video for this question and answer since there are some things which can be visualized better in a graphical video. It visualizes and also updates this answer with the knowledge and experience which I got in the last years using Docker on multiple systems (and also K8s).

While this question was asked in the context of ASP.NET Core, it is not really related to this framework. The problem was a lack of basic understanding of Docker concepts, so it can happen with nearly every application and framework. For that reason, I used a simple Nginx webserver here since I think many of you are familiar with web servers, but not everyone knows how specific frameworks like ASP.NET Core works.

The underlying problem is to understand the difference between containers vs images and how they are different in their lifecycle, which is the basic topic of this video.

### Textual answer (Originally from 2016)

After some research and testing, I found that I had some misunderstandings about the lifetime of Docker containers. Simply restarting a container doesn't make Docker use a new image, when the image was rebuilt in the meantime. Instead, Docker is fetching the image only *before* creating the container. So the state after running a container is persistent.

#### Why removing is required

Therefore, rebuilding and restarting isn't enough. I thought containers work like a service: Stop the service, do your changes, restart it and they would apply. That was my biggest mistake.

Because containers are permanent, you have to remove them using `docker rm <ContainerName>` first. After a container is removed, you can't simply start it by `docker start`. This has to be done using `docker run`, which itself uses the latest image for creating a new container instance.

#### Containers should be as independent as possible

With this knowledge, it's comprehensible why storing data in containers is [considered a bad practice](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/24/10-things-to-avoid-in-docker-containers/) and Docker recommends [data volumes/mounting host directories](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) instead: Since a container has to be destroyed to update applications, the stored data inside would be lost too. This causes extra work to shutdown services, back up data and so on.

So it's a smart solution to exclude those data completely from the container: We don't have to worry about our data, when it's stored safely on the host and the container only holds the application itself.

#### Why `-rf` may not really help you

The `docker run` command, has a *clean up* switch called `-rf`. It will stop the behavior of keeping Docker containers permanently. Using `-rf`, Docker will destroy the container after it has been exited. But this switch has a problem: Docker also removes the volumes without a name associated with the container, which may kill your data.

While the `-rf` switch is a good option to save work during development for quick tests, it's less suitable in production. Especially because of the missing option to run a container in the background, which would mostly be required.

#### How to remove a container

We can bypass those limitations by simply removing the container:

```
docker rm --force <ContainerName>
```

The `--force` (or `-f`) switch which uses SIGKILL on running containers. Instead, you could also stop the container before:

```
docker stop <ContainerName>
docker rm <ContainerName>
```

Both are equal. `docker stop` also uses [SIGTERM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/). But using the `--force` switch will shorten your script, especially when using CI servers: `docker stop` throws an error if the container is not running. This would cause Jenkins and many other CI servers to consider the build wrongly as failed. To fix this, you have to check first if the container is running as I did in the question (see `containerRunning` variable).

#### There is a better way (Added 2016)

While plain docker commands like `docker build`, `docker run` and others are a good way for beginners to understand basic concepts, it's getting annoying when you're already familiar with Docker and want to get productive. A better way is to use Docker-Compose. While it's designed for multi-container environments, it also gives you benefits when using standalone with a single container. Although multi-container environments aren't really uncommon. Nearly every application has at least an application server and some database. Some even more like caching servers, cron containers or other things.

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  my-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Now you can just use `docker-compose up --build` and compose will take care of all the steps which I did manually. I'd prefer this one over the script with plain Docker commands, which I added as an answer from 2016. It still works, but is more complex and it won't handle certain situations as well as docker-compose would. For example, compose checks if everything is up to date and only rebuilds those things which need to be rebuilt because of changes.

Especially when you're using multiple containers, compose offers way more benefits. For example, linking the containers which requires creating/maintaining networks manually otherwise. You can also specify dependencies so that a database container is started before the application server, which depends on the DB at startup.

In the past with Docker-Compose 1.x I noticed some issues, especially with caching. This results in containers not being updated, even when something had changed. I have tested compose v2 for some time now without seeing any of those issues again, so it seems to be fixed now.

#### Full script for rebuilding a Docker container (original answer from 2016)

According to this new knowledge, I fixed my script in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
imageName=xx:my-image
containerName=my-container

docker build -t $imageName -f Dockerfile  .

echo Delete old container...
docker rm -f $containerName

echo Run new container...
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name $containerName $imageName
```

This works perfectly :)

Comment: 'I found that I had some misunderstandings about the lifetime of Docker containers' you took the words right out of my mouth. Thank you for such detailed explanation. I would recommend this to docker newbies. This clarifies the difference of VM vs container.

Comment: After your explanation, what I did is to take note of what I did to my existing image. In order to have changes retained, I created a new Dockerfile to create a new image which already includes changes that I want to add. That way, the new image created is (somewhat) updated.

Comment: Is the `--force-recreate` option on docker compose similar to what you describe here? And if so, wouldn't it be worth to use this solution instead (sorry if that question is dumb but I'm a docker noob ^^)

Comment: @cglacet Yes, it's similar, not directly compareable. But `docker-compose` is smarter than the plain `docker` commands. I work regularly with `docker-compose` and the change detection works well, so I use `--force-recreate` very rarely. Just `docker-compose up --build` is important when you're building a custom image (`build` directive in compose file) instead of using an image from e.g. the Docker hub.

Comment: how do you use this script?

Comment: After making any small changes in code, I have to build docker image again and then push it to azure container repository. Which takes too much time. Is there any way to push latest changes in docker image by not consuming too much time?

Comment: Thank god for this answer. One simple command to make it easy to rebuild (yet somehow ten million other threads fail to list it): docker-compose up --build

Comment: Earlier this year Docker added an experimental [watch feature](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-experiment-sync-files-and-automatically-rebuild-services-with-watch-mode/) that works pretty well for the most part. The only issue I've faced so far is that when it rebuilds, volumes are not remounted (even named volumes).

Answer (score 89):

Whenever changes are made in dockerfile or compose or requirements, re-run it using `docker-compose up --build`. So that images get rebuilt and refreshed

Comment: Having a MySQL docker container as one service, would the DB be empty after that if one used a volume for `/opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: To me, there doesn't seem any downside to just always using `--build` in local dev environments.

The speed at which docker re-copies the files it might otherwise assume don't need copying take only a couple of milliseconds, and it saves large number of WTF moments.

Comment: This worked for me seamlessly and without problem, thanks.

Comment: this must be acceptable answer

Answer (score 4):

You can run `build` for a specific service by running `docker-compose up --build <service name>` where the service name must match how did you call it in your docker-compose file.

**Example**
Let's assume that your docker-compose file contains many services (.net app - database - let's encrypt... etc) and you want to update only the .net app which named as `application` in docker-compose file.
You can then simply run `docker-compose up --build application`

**Extra parameters**
In case you want to add extra parameters to your command such as `-d` for running in the background, the parameter must be before the service name:
`docker-compose up --build -d application`

Answer (score 0):

You can force a rebuild just from the copy rather than having to do a full rebuild.

add a line similar to

```
RUN mkdir -p /BUILD_TOKEN/f7e0188ea2c8466ebf77bf37eb6ab1c1
COPY src src
```

The mkdir call is just to have a line that docker must execute which contains the token we are going to change each time we need a partial rebuild.

Now have your build script replace the uuid whenever you need to force a copy

In dart I do:

```dart
  if (parsed['clone'] as bool == true) {
    final uuid = const Uuid().v4().replaceAll('-', '');

    replace(dockerfilePath, RegExp('RUN mkdir -p /BUILD_TOKEN/.*'),
        'RUN mkdir -p /BUILD_TOKEN/$uuid');
  }
```

I then run my build tool as:

```sh
build.dart --clone
```

This is my full dart script but it has some extraneous bits:

```dart
#! /usr/bin/env dcli

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
import 'package:unpubd/src/version/version.g.dart';

/// build and publish the unpubd docker container.
void main(List<String> args) {
  final parser = ArgParser()
    ..addFlag('clean',
        abbr: 'c', help: 'Force a full rebuild of the docker container')
    ..addFlag('clone', abbr: 'l', help: 'Force reclone of the git repo.');

  ArgResults parsed;
  try {
    parsed = parser.parse(args);
  } on FormatException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    print(parser.usage);
    exit(1);
  }
  final dockerfilePath =
      join(DartProject.self.pathToProjectRoot, 'resources', 'Dockerfile');

  'dcli pack'.run;

  print(blue('Building unpubd $packageVersion'));

  final tag = 'noojee/unpubd:$packageVersion';
  const latest = 'noojee/unpubd:latest';

  var clean = '';
  if (parsed['clean'] as bool == true) {
    clean = ' --no-cache';
  }

  if (parsed['clone'] as bool == true) {
    final uuid = const Uuid().v4().replaceAll('-', '');
    replace(dockerfilePath, RegExp('RUN mkdir -p /BUILD_TOKEN/.*'),
        'RUN mkdir -p /BUILD_TOKEN/$uuid');
  }

  'docker  build $clean -t $tag -t $latest -f $dockerfilePath .'.run;

  'docker push noojee/unpubd:$packageVersion'.run;
  'docker push $tag'.run;
  'docker push $latest'.run;
}
```

Comment: This would better answer "Rebuild Docker IMAGE on file changes", but you don't need "to have a line that docker must execute", you need changed _content_ (at every stage).  Docker will _automatically_ rerun a build step if its input changes, but this is based on content hashing without considering timestamps.  In my case changing code comments led to the application being rebuilt, but the output hashed the same so the LATER COPY step (in a multi-staged build) used cached results and yielded "old" files.